# "retrieving the com class factory for component with clsid" showing this error when connecting with dll.?

Tags: c#, dll

I am using 64 bit windows server 2008 machine,I tried to connect an ERP dll with c# code.But showing this error "retrieving the com class factory for component with clsid...." when running the application.I registered the dll using the command "regsvr32 Interop.AccpacCOMAPI.dll".Then this time error is "dll may not compatible with the version of  windows that you are running..".How can I run the application.Please help.

Comment: Do *not* try to register the .NET interop library.  Many possible reasons to have trouble, but number one is the bitness of your process.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, run Regsvr32.exe from the% SystemRoot% \ Syswow64. For example, type in the Start \ Run the following command to register the DLL:

\ windows \ syswow64 \ regsvr32  Interop.AccpacCOMAPI.dll

Comment: Hi Aghilas Yakoub,I tried with that,but this time shows the error Interop.AccpacCOMAPI.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Comment: corrupted version of your dll may be in memory. use Pview to detect and remove the old file